# Getting values from Entry() in Python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I've got a little problem while creating the GUI for my Python program.

In the code, i've implemented this function:

```
def simula_partita(modello, squadraCasa, squadraOspite, max_gol=10):
    media_gol_casa = modello.predict(pd.DataFrame(data={'Squadra': squadraCasa,
                                                    'Avversaria': squadraOspite, 'Casa':1},
                                                    index=[1])).values[0]
    media_gol_ospiti = modello.predict(pd.DataFrame(data={'Squadra': squadraOspite,
                                                    'Avversaria': squadraCasa, 'Casa':0},
                                                    index=[1])).values[0]
    previsione_squadra = [[poisson.pmf(i, media_squadra) for i in range(0, max_gol+1)] 
    for media_squadra in [media_gol_casa, media_gol_ospiti]]

    ris = np.outer(np.array(previsione_squadra[0]), np.array(previsione_squadra[1]))
    print(ris)
    return(ris)
```

It takes four arguments (modello, squadraCasa, squadraOspite, max_gol).

If I call it in the code, like this:

```
simula_partita(modello_poisson, 'Juventus', 'Liverpool', max_gol=4)
```

It goes smoothly and gives me the desidered output.

Now, at the end of the code, I tried doing a GUI with this code:

```
    root = Tk()

m = StringVar()
c = StringVar()
o = StringVar()
g = StringVar()

sceltaModello = Entry(root, textvariable = m)
sceltaCasa = Entry(root, textvariable = c)
sceltaOspite = Entry(root, textvariable = o)
sceltaGol = Entry(root, textvariable = g)

sceltaModello.pack()
sceltaCasa.pack()
sceltaOspite.pack()
sceltaGol.pack()

m.set('modello_poisson')
c.set('Squadra di Casa')
o.set('Squadra Ospite')
g.set('Max Gol')

modello = m.get()
squadraCasa = c.get()
squadraOspite = o.get()
max_gol = g.get()

avvia = Button(root, text = "Avvia Simulazione", command = simula_partita)

avvia.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

My wish was to get "modello", "squadraCasa", "squadraOspite" and "max_gol" as the Entry() input, but it doesn't seems to work and it gives me the error that the function "simula_partita" needs those parameters.

Could you help me figure out this problem?
Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Even if `simula_partita()` somehow magically received its parameter values from the global variables that coincidentally have the same names as those parameters, this still wouldn't work because those variables were retrieved from the `Entry`s just a moment after their creation - there is absolutely no possibility that they will contain any user-entered data (and aren't the right types, anyway).  You need to write a function that takes zero parameters (so that it's valid for the `command=` option) and does the `.get()`s and calls `simula_partita()` with the right parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Your function is defined with 4 parameters. You have to pass those parameters when the function is called via the command option in the Button. I don't exactly know what you function does, so, i'll replace it to print the 4 parameters for now.

```
from tkinter import *
import sqlite3
root = Tk()
def simula_partita(modello, squadraCasa, squadraOspite, max_gol=10):
    print(modello, squadraCasa, squadraOspite, max_gol)

m = StringVar()
c = StringVar()
o = StringVar()
g = StringVar()

sceltaModello = Entry(root, textvariable = m)
sceltaCasa = Entry(root, textvariable = c)
sceltaOspite = Entry(root, textvariable = o)
sceltaGol = Entry(root, textvariable = g)

sceltaModello.pack()
sceltaCasa.pack()
sceltaOspite.pack()
sceltaGol.pack()

m.set('modello_poisson')
c.set('Squadra di Casa')
o.set('Squadra Ospite')
g.set('Max Gol')

avvia = Button(root, text = "Avvia Simulazione", command = lambda: simula_partita(m.get(), c.get(), o.get(), g.get()))
avvia.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

**Edit: To answer OP's specific question**

The entry field has to be set to a string. I understand that you are trying to pass as argument a variable. But the output of the entry field will be a string.

What you can do is create a dict with the string as key and the variable as value (ie 'data' in the below code) and the send the variable like `data[m.get()]`. If you have more variable that can be give you can add it as another key value pair in that dictionary.

Also the 4th parameter is an int so i have made it an int before passing using int().

Try changing to these lines in your full code.

```
m.set('modello_poisson')
c.set('Squadra di Casa')
o.set('Squadra Ospite')
g.set('Max Gol')
data={'modello_poisson':modello_poisson}
avvia = Button(root, text = "Avvia Simulazione", command = lambda: simula_partita(data[m.get()], c.get(), o.get(), int(g.get())))
```

I gave the following in the 4 entry fields entries

```
modello_poisson 
Juventus
Atalanta
4
```

and got an output

```
[[0.03608837 0.03099437 0.0133097  0.00381033 0.00081812]
 [0.08888343 0.07633721 0.03278097 0.00938461 0.00201498]
 [0.1094572  0.09400692 0.04036875 0.01155685 0.00248139]
 [0.0898621  0.07717774 0.03314191 0.00948794 0.00203717]
 [0.0553312  0.047521   0.02040662 0.00584205 0.00125436]]
```

printed to my console.

Comment: @Noshirt If you can somehow put in your entire code i can try.

Comment: Benninchan, ok, look at my next answer

Comment: @Noshirt I think i may have solved your problem. See my edited answer.

Answer (score -1):

Full code:

```
    import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn
from scipy.stats import poisson,skellam
from tkinter import *

serieA_1819 = pd.read_csv("http://www.football-data.co.uk/mmz4281/1819/I1.csv")
serieA_1819 = serieA_1819[['HomeTeam','AwayTeam','FTHG','FTAG']]
serieA_1819 = serieA_1819.rename(columns={'FTHG': 'GolCasa', 'FTAG': 'GolOspiti'})
serieA_1819.head()
print(serieA_1819.head())

# Faccio una media dei gol segnati dalla squadra di casa e quelli segnati dalla squadra ospite.
# Come si può notare dall'output, generalmente la squadra di casa ha una media gol più alta.
# Questo fenomeno viene definito come "Home Field Advantage".
serieA_1819.mean()
print(serieA_1819.mean())

# Costruisco una distribuzione di Poisson per ogni media gol.
# La distribuzione di Poisson è una distribuzione di probabilità discreta,
# che descrive la probabilità che si verifichino un determinato numero di eventi
# in un arco di tempo predefinito (nel caso di una partita di calcio, 90 minuti),
# basandosi su un tasso di verifica dell'evento già noto.
poisson_pred = np.column_stack([[poisson.pmf(i, serieA_1819.mean()[j]) for i in range(8)] for j in range(2)])

# Plotto l'istogramma dei gol
plt.hist(serieA_1819[['GolCasa', 'GolOspiti']].values, range(9), 
         alpha=0.7, label=['Casa', 'Ospiti'],density=True, color=["#41FF32", "#20B2AA"])

# Aggiungo le linee per la distribuzione di Poisson
pois1, = plt.plot([i-0.5 for i in range(1,9)], poisson_pred[:,0],
                  linestyle='-', marker='o',label="Casa", color = '#000080')
pois2, = plt.plot([i-0.5 for i in range(1,9)], poisson_pred[:,1],
                  linestyle='-', marker='o',label="Ospiti", color = '#FF0000')

legenda=plt.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize=13, ncol=2)
legenda.set_title("Poisson           Reale        ", prop = {'size':'14', 'weight':'bold'})

plt.xticks([i-0.5 for i in range(1,9)],[i for i in range(9)])
plt.xlabel("Gol a Partita",size=13)
plt.ylabel("Proporzione per Partita",size=13)
plt.title("Numero di Gol per Partita (Serie A 2018/2019)",size=14,fontweight='bold')
plt.ylim([-0.004, 0.4])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

# Ovviamente il numero di gol segnato da una squadra è indipendente dall'altro.
# La differenza tra due distribuzioni di Poisson viene chiamata "Distribuzione di Skellam",
# che ci permetterà di calcolare le probabilità che la partita finisca in pareggio
# o con la vittoria di una delle due squadre.
# Effettuo una previsione dei gol basandomi sulla distribuzione di Skellam

prev_skellam = [skellam.pmf(i, serieA_1819.mean()[0], serieA_1819.mean()[1]) for i in range(-6,8)]

plt.hist(serieA_1819[['GolCasa']].values - serieA_1819[['GolOspiti']].values, range(-6,8),
        alpha=0.7, label='Reale',density=True)
plt.plot([i+0.5 for i in range(-6,8)], prev_skellam,
                linestyle='-', marker='o', label="Skellam", color='#FF0000')
plt.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize=13)
plt.xticks([i+0.5 for i in range(-6,8)],[i for i in range(-6,8)])
plt.xlabel("Gol Casa - Gol Ospiti", size=13)
plt.ylabel("Proporzione per partita", size=13)
plt.title("Differenza Gol segnati (Squadra di Casa vs Squadra Ospite)", size=14, fontweight='bold')
plt.ylim([-0.004, 0.30])
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

# Per adattare questo modello a una partita specifica, dobbiamo conoscere
# il numero medio di gol segnati per partita da ogni squadra.
# Utilizziamo come esempio Juventus e Inter.

fig,(ax1,ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1)

# Creo delle distribuzioni di Poisson sui gol fatti in casa e fuori casa di entrambe le squadre

inter_casa = serieA_1819[serieA_1819['HomeTeam']=='Inter'][['GolCasa']].apply(pd.value_counts, normalize=True)
inter_casa_poisson = [poisson.pmf(i, np.sum(np.multiply(inter_casa.values.T, inter_casa.index.T), axis=1)[0])
for i in range(8)]

juve_casa = serieA_1819[serieA_1819['HomeTeam']=='Juventus'][['GolCasa']].apply(pd.value_counts, normalize=True)
juve_casa_poisson = [poisson.pmf(i, np.sum(np.multiply(juve_casa.values.T, juve_casa.index.T), axis=1)[0])
for i in range(8)]

inter_ospiti = serieA_1819[serieA_1819['AwayTeam']=='Inter'][['GolOspiti']].apply(pd.value_counts, normalize=True)
inter_ospiti_poisson = [poisson.pmf(i, np.sum(np.multiply(inter_ospiti.values.T, inter_ospiti.index.T), axis=1)[0])
for i in range(8)]

juve_ospiti = serieA_1819[serieA_1819['AwayTeam']=='Juventus'][['GolOspiti']].apply(pd.value_counts, normalize=True)
juve_ospiti_poisson = [poisson.pmf(i, np.sum(np.multiply(juve_ospiti.values.T, juve_ospiti.index.T), axis=1)[0])
for i in range(8)]

# Questa è stata la parte che mi ha fatto smadonnare di più.
# Inizialmente i vettori "squadra_casa.values" e "squadra_ospiti.values" davano errore
# poiché venivano interpretati come vettori in 2D anzichè in 1D.
# Dopo varie analisi e ricerche su internet (le consiglio, se non lo conosce già,
# il forum "StackOverflow", veramente ben fornito, mi hanno aiutato a risolvere in meno di 5 minuti.),
# ho scoperto che bastava aggiungere ".flatten()" al vettore per poterlo avere in 1D.
# Questo ha risolto il mio problema, e in questa parte, sempre tramite la distribuzione di Poisson,
# genero un grafico che mi fa vedere le statistiche riguardo i gol fatti dalle due squadre
# quando giocano in casa e quando giocano fuori casa.

ax1.bar(inter_casa.index-0.4, inter_casa.values.flatten(), width=0.4, color="#034694", label="Inter")
ax1.bar(juve_casa.index, juve_casa.values.flatten(), width=0.4, color="#000000", label="Juventus")

pois1, = ax1.plot([i for i in range(8)], inter_casa_poisson,
                    linestyle='-', marker='o', label="Inter", color="#0A7BFF")

pois1, = ax1.plot([i for i in range(8)], juve_casa_poisson,
                    linestyle='-', marker='o', label="Juventus", color="#FF7C89")

legenda = ax1.legend(loc='upper right', fontsize=12, ncol=2)
legenda.set_title("Poisson           Reale           ", prop={'size':'14', 'weight':'bold'})
ax1.set_xlim([-0.5,7.5])
ax1.set_ylim([-0.01,0.65])
ax1.set_xticklabels([])

ax1.text(7.65, 0.585, '                Casa                ', rotation=-90,
        bbox={'facecolor':'#FFBCF6', 'alpha':0.5, 'pad':5})

ax2.text(7.65, 0.585, '                Ospiti                ', rotation=-90,
        bbox={'facecolor':'#FFBCF6', 'alpha':0.5, 'pad':5})

ax2.bar(inter_ospiti.index-0.4, inter_ospiti.values.flatten(), width=0.4, color="#034694", label="Inter")
ax2.bar(juve_ospiti.index, juve_ospiti.values.flatten(), width=0.4, color="#000000", label="Juventus")

pois1, = ax2.plot([i for i in range(8)], inter_ospiti_poisson,
                    linestyle='-', marker='o', label="Inter", color="#0A7BFF")

pois1, = ax2.plot([i for i in range(8)], juve_ospiti_poisson,
                    linestyle='-', marker='o', label="Juventus", color="#FF7C89")

ax2.set_xlim([-0.5,7.5])
ax2.set_ylim([-0.01,0.65])
ax1.set_title("Numero di Gol per Partita (Serie A 2018/2019)", size=14, fontweight='bold')
ax2.set_xlabel("Gol per Partita", size=13)
ax2.text(-1.15, 0.9, 'Proporzione per Partita', rotation=90, size=13)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()

# Ora costruirò un modello di Regressione di Poisson per analizzare
# tutti i risultati possibili per ogni partita possibile.

# Citando Wikipedia: La regressione di Poisson assume che 
# la variabile di risposta Y ha una distribuzione di Poisson, 
# e assume che il logaritmo del suo valore aspettato possa essere modellato 
# da una combinazione lineare di parametri sconosciuti.

import statsmodels.api as sm
import statsmodels.formula.api as smf

modello_gol = pd.concat([serieA_1819[['HomeTeam','AwayTeam','GolCasa']].assign(Casa=1).rename(
        columns={'HomeTeam':'Squadra', 'AwayTeam':'Avversaria','GolCasa':'Gol'}),
        serieA_1819[['AwayTeam','HomeTeam','GolOspiti']].assign(Casa=0).rename(
        columns={'AwayTeam':'Squadra', 'HomeTeam':'Avversaria', 'GolOspiti':'Gol'})])

modello_poisson = smf.glm(formula="Gol ~ Casa + Squadra + Avversaria", data=modello_gol,
                        family=sm.families.Poisson()).fit()
modello_poisson.summary()
print(modello_poisson.summary())

# Cosa significa l'output di questa porzione di codice?
# Il modello della distribuzione di Poisson avviene tramite
# il "GLM", ovvero un "Modello Lineare Generalizzato".
# Il paramentro da prendere in considerazione è quello della
# colonna "coef".
# Esso è da intendere come il coefficiente che indica la probabilità
# che la squadra faccia gol, utilizzandolo come esponente di "e".
# Un valore positivo di "coef" indica una maggiore possibilità di segnare,
# mentre un valore più vicino allo zero indica una neutralità (e^0 = 1).
# Alla fine della lista è possibile notare che "Casa" ha un valore "coef" di 0.2510.
# Ciò significa che la squadra che gioca in casa ha più probabilità di fare gol
# (nello specifico, e^0.2510 = 1.28 volte più probabile che segni).
# Ovviamente non tutte le squadre hanno lo stesso livello.
# Andando ad analizzare, per esempio, Frosinone e Sampdoria,
# i valori di "coef" sono -1.1868 (Frosinone) e -0.2197 (Sampdoria).
# Da ciò si evince appunto che la Sampdoria ha molte più probabilità
# di fare gol (0.80) rispetto al Frosinone (0.30).
# Se andiamo invece ad analizzare lo stesso valore quando la squadra è ospite,
# viene considerata quindi come "Avversaria", un valore più alto di "coef" indica 
# una minor probabilità di poter segnare contro quella squadra,
# ovvero la probabilità che quella squadra ha di non subire gol.
# Prendiamo ad esempio Roma e Lazio.
# La Roma come avversaria ha un "coef" di -0.1366, mentre la Lazio -0.2766.
# Questo significa che avrei più probabilità di segnare contro
# la Lazio (0.75) che contro la Roma (0.87).

# Andiamo ora ad effettuare delle previsioni su alcune partite.
# Il modello Poissoniano riceverà come parametri le due squadre,
# e restituirà come output il valore medio di gol che ogni squadra potrebbe segnare.
# Ipotizziamo una partita Genoa - Milan.

gol_genoa_vs_milan = modello_poisson.predict(pd.DataFrame(data={'Squadra': 'Genoa', 'Avversaria': 'Milan',
                                        'Casa':1},index=[1]))
print(gol_genoa_vs_milan)

gol_milan_vs_genoa = modello_poisson.predict(pd.DataFrame(data={'Squadra': 'Milan', 'Avversaria':'Genoa',
                                        'Casa':0},index=[1]))
print(gol_milan_vs_genoa)

# Queste due previsioni ci daranno in output la probabilità di segnare delle due squadre.
# Ora definisco una funzione che simula una partita tra due squadre che andrò a inserire come parametri.

def simula_partita(modello, squadraCasa, squadraOspite, max_gol=10):
        media_gol_casa = modello.predict(pd.DataFrame(data={'Squadra': squadraCasa,
                                                        'Avversaria': squadraOspite, 'Casa':1},
                                                        index=[1])).values[0]
        media_gol_ospiti = modello.predict(pd.DataFrame(data={'Squadra': squadraOspite,
                                                        'Avversaria': squadraCasa, 'Casa':0},
                                                        index=[1])).values[0]
        previsione_squadra = [[poisson.pmf(i, media_squadra) for i in range(0, max_gol+1)] 
        for media_squadra in [media_gol_casa, media_gol_ospiti]]

        ris = np.outer(np.array(previsione_squadra[0]), np.array(previsione_squadra[1]))
        print(ris)
        return(ris)

# Dopo aver definito la funzione, provo a simulare una partita.
# Scelgo Fiorentina - Sassuolo.

simula_partita(modello_poisson, 'Fiorentina', 'Sassuolo', max_gol=4)

# Come si può notare dall'output, la funzione dà come risultato una matrice.
# Le righe della matrice rappresentano le probabilità della squadra di casa
# (in questo caso la Fiorentina), di segnare da 0 a max_gol,
# mentre le colonne rappresentano la stessa probabilità per la squadra
# ospite, (in questo caso il Sassuolo).
# Lungo la diagonale si trovano le varie probabilità di pareggio, che vanno
# dal caso 0-0 al caso 4-4.
# Sommando tutti gli elementi della diagonale, si ottiene la probabilità di pareggio.
# Se sommiamo gli elementi sotto la diagonale, otteniamo le probabilità di vittoria
# della squadra di casa, mentre la somma degli elementi sopra la diagonale ci darà
# la probabilità di vittoria della squadra ospite.

# Arriviamo dunque alla parte finale del programma, quella che io (e probabilmente anche lei, immagino),
# utilizzeremo per giocarci le future schedine. Ovviamente non garantisco un 100% di affidabilità,
# ma suppongo che affidarsi alla statistica a volte sia megio che farlo all'intuito.
# Il 19 Gennaio ricomincia la Serie A.
# Sfrutteremo l'occasione per calcolare i possibili risultati di alcune partite.

print("Risultati Udinese - Parma")
udinese_parma = simula_partita(modello_poisson, 'Udinese', 'Parma', max_gol=6)

# Vittoria dell'Udinese
udinese_vince_parma = np.sum(np.tril(udinese_parma, -1))
print("Vittoria Udinese:", "{0:.2f}".format(udinese_vince_parma*100), "%")

# Vittoria del Parma
parma_vince_udinese = np.sum(np.triu(udinese_parma, 1))
print("Vittoria Parma:", "{0:.2f}".format(parma_vince_udinese*100), "%")

# Pareggio
pareggio_udinese_parma = np.sum(np.diag(udinese_parma))
print("Pareggio:", "{0:.2f}".format(pareggio_udinese_parma*100), "%")

print("Risultati Napoli - Lazio")
napoli_lazio = simula_partita(modello_poisson, 'Napoli', 'Lazio', max_gol=6)

# Vittoria del Napoli
napoli_vince_lazio = np.sum(np.tril(napoli_lazio, -1))
print("Vittoria Napoli:", "{0:.2f}".format(napoli_vince_lazio*100), "%")

# Vittoria della Lazio
lazio_vince_napoli = np.sum(np.triu(napoli_lazio, 1))
print("Vittoria Lazio:", "{0:.2f}".format(lazio_vince_napoli*100), "%")

# Pareggio
pareggio_napoli_lazio = np.sum(np.diag(napoli_lazio))
print("Pareggio:", "{0:.2f}".format(pareggio_napoli_lazio*100), "%")

root = Tk()

m = StringVar()
c = StringVar()
o = StringVar()
g = StringVar()

sceltaModello = Entry(root, textvariable = m)
sceltaCasa = Entry(root, textvariable = c)
sceltaOspite = Entry(root, textvariable = o)
sceltaGol = Entry(root, textvariable = g)

sceltaModello.pack()
sceltaCasa.pack()
sceltaOspite.pack()
sceltaGol.pack()

m.set(modello_poisson)
c.set(Squadra di Casa)
o.set(Squadra Ospite)
g.set(Max Gol)

avvia = Button(root, text = "Avvia Simulazione", command = lambda: simula_partita(m.get(), c.get(), o.get(), g.get()))

avvia.pack()
root.mainloop()
```